# Installing Windows when using Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I have got Ubuntu 12.04 and want to install Windows 8. But I can't install Windows 8 as my hard disk is in FAT32 format and Windows 8 needs NTFS. I tried to format my hard disk (there are no partitions in the hard disk) but couldn't as a message appears that it is mounted.

I tried to unmount it but couldn't. Also my Software Center is not working. It opens and within seconds closes. Kindly help me. I need to install Windows 8 as soon as possible. If not Windows 8, then  at least Windows 7. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider fixing the Software Center's issue before installing Windows 8.

Comment: Your hard drive must have a partition if you have installed Ubuntu to it...

Comment: If you only need Windows to use a Windows application, you might consider installing PlayOnLinux, an application that you can use to use Windows applications inside Ubuntu. You can install it with Software Center. But then you will need to fix Software Center first.

Comment: Please split your question (the software centre issue is a separate question) and post the Windows question on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a live USB/DVD to partition the disk, as the file system is locked when you use it. You can download the live disk from Ubuntu's [website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Once you have booted the live disk, open Gparted and format the disk.

However, Windows's installer should also be able to format and partition the disk appropriately.